# Repeat a table on all pages in a SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a legend table that I want to repeat on all pages of the report. Ideally I wanted to include this table in the footer of the report. But SSRS does NOT allow me to add a table to the report footer. Is there any way where I can  repeat this table on all pages of the report? Please be kind enough to provide  me with an answer.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a rectangle first?

Comment: No what does the rectangle do ? I need to repeat a table on all pages.

Comment: You don't need tags for obvious things. SQL Server is obviously a Microsoft product, so the Microsoft tag is not needed. Please limit your tags to those that are actually meaningful to your question. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I feel from your question is the table you mention seems not to be too big, as you want it to be in the **footer** of the report
So what you can do is insert the Page Footer in the report.

Create the table that you want in the report footer with the help of TextBoxes and other toolbar items--- by enabling the border on all 4-sides of textboxes and then write the stuff you want in the table, then simply drag it to your footer.

It should look like a table on all the pages of the report ! :)